# remove the row with multiple values in a dataframe and also seperate the multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

1.**Input:** dataframe I have contains a and b values in name

```
ID name
1  a1/x,b1
2  a1,a2v,a3,d12,L2c,f13/w
3  a5,a6,C3,b2/y
4  a8/g,b9/p
```

2.**Expected Output_1:** I want to remove all the names which contains more than 1 a and 1 b values

```
ID name
1  a1/x,b1
4  a8/g,b9/p
```

3.**Expected Output_2:** I want the multiple name values to split into single a and b values as follows

```
ID name
1  a1/x,b1
2  a1,d12
3  a2v,L2c
4  a3,f13/w
5  a5,C3
6  a6,b2/y
7  a8/g,b9/p
```

I earlier had the data in [[a1,a2],[b1,b3]] this form of list, then removed the brackets and took the data as per input.

**Code I tried**

**Output_2 code:**
df["name"]= df["name"].str.split(",").explode().agg(",".join))
df

but it is not working and i am yet to figure out code for output_1.

Answer (score 1):

For output 1:

```py
df = df[~df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.count("a") > 1 and x.count("b") > 1)]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   name
0   1  a1,b1
3   4  a8,b9
```

For output 2:

```py
def fn(x):
    l = x.split(",")
    a = [v for v in l if v.startswith("a")]
    b = [v for v in l if v.startswith("b")]
    return list(map(list, zip(a, b)))


df["name"] = df["name"].apply(fn)
df = df.explode("name").reset_index(drop=True)
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(",".join)
df["ID"] = df.index + 1
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   ID   name
0   1  a1,b1
1   2  a1,b1
2   3  a2,b2
3   4  a3,b3
4   5  a5,b3
5   6  a6,b2
6   7  a8,b9
```

---

EDIT: With updated input data:

Output 1:

```py
df = df[~df["name"].apply(lambda x: x.count("a") > 1 or x.count("b") > 1)]
print(df)

   ID       name
0   1    a1/x,b1
3   4  a8/g,b9/p
```

Output 2:

```py
def fn(x):
    l = x.split(",")
    a = [v for v in l if v.startswith("a")]
    b = [v for v in l if not v.startswith("a")]
    return list(map(list, zip(a, b)))


df["name"] = df["name"].apply(fn)
df = df.explode("name").reset_index(drop=True)
df["name"] = df["name"].apply(",".join)
df["ID"] = df.index + 1
print(df)

   ID       name
0   1    a1/x,b1
1   2     a1,d12
2   3    a2v,L2c
3   4   a3,f13/w
4   5      a5,C3
5   6    a6,b2/y
6   7  a8/g,b9/p
```

Comment: for output_1 code, the B values can be anything example c123 or L528.
So it wont be feasible

Comment: Should i put something like not a for b values?

Comment: @Anubhav Please edit your question and put there more realistic data. This example works only for `a` and `b` values.

Comment: the edited code will still only work with a and b, but the b can have other values instead also. like c3, d1/x etc. So its the not filtering right for all data

Comment: i have thousands of data rows. a is fine but the second part can vary

Comment: @Anubhav Do you mean this: `print(df[df["name"].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(",")) == 2)])` ?